# Extra "lines" are being added when creating/editing questions/answers in Edge

Tags: bug, editor

Lately, I've noticed that extra lines are being added when I create questions/answers. For example, if I write:

```
Your problem is X, Y, Z. Fix it by doing:

    Code

Then maybe also do some other thing.

Oh, and some other thing as well.
```

When I post it, then go back into the editor, it's been changed to:

```
Your problem is X, Y, Z. Fix it by doing:


    Code


Then maybe also do some other thing.


Oh, and some other thing as well.
```

Which is mildly annoying since that causes less to be displayed in the box at once, but whatever.

The weird thing is though, the added line isn't properly treated as a newline, even though it does appear to be caused by a newline. A lot of lines that look like they should be empty don't even get rendered. If I delete the original lines that I entered leaving only the "new" newlines, I get weird behavior:

[image]

I tried selecting the characters involved and inspecting them in Python, and they just appear to be newlines, so I have no idea what the problem is.

---

The only browser I've been able to reproduce it in is Edge (version 44.18362.329.0). It does not happen in Chrome. This has been happening for ~3 days now.

---

There is also a problem with link embedding and code formatting. If while editing I highlight some text and either try to embed a link (interlinked circle button) or format it as code (`{}` button), it often puts the wrong text between the `[…]`s when embedding, or formats code that I didn't highlight (and doesn't format the code that I did highlight).

Comment: FYI, in case you didn't see it, about a month ago I asked [Microsoft Edge browser can't display certain SE pages and sometimes abruptly exits when editing, but apparently only when involving MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344433/562482). I was then using a slightly more recent version than you, i.e., 44.18362.449.0. My problems seemed to be related to MathJax handling, with quite significant issues as I described. My solution to allow me to continue using Edge was to update to the beta version using the Chrome engine, with no problems since then. You may wish to try this yourself.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Unfortunately, it's a school-issued laptop, and they have strict policies in place regarding updating. I'm not sure I'd be able to alter Edge. I can see though, thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, like you I also just noticed this behaviour with the blank lines appearing in the last week. While updating to a new version may fix the problem, I still find it curious that we both noticed the behaviour change only recently. My version of Edge was last updated at the beginning of Feb. I was hoping someone from SE could comment if they are aware of any problems.

Comment: For three to five days, they've been transitioning from .NET to .NET Core. Be patient, it will get done and then we won't have to deal with Windows Updates.

Comment: I'll add too, all sorts of editing functionality is suddenly (still) broken in Edge. If I highlight some text then click the button to embed a link in it, after I click OK in the dialog, the wrong text was put between the `[]`! It's inconsistent too. It'll fail to do it right two or three times in a row, then without changing anything, it will work on the fourth try. It's a similar case with the `{}` button that formats code. I'll highlight code, hit that button, and suddenly the formatting is completely destroyed because it formatted the wrong text. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is an absurd browser. The mainstream is Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @iBugisdisappointedinSE That's true, but it worked fine until April. I can't afford to have Chrome or Firefox open though. Both are hogs. If I have a couple VMs running with maybe PyCharm, and 20 tabs in a browser open, Chrome and Firefox will often be the straw that frees my computer, while Edge trucks along fine.